# iOS remote notification not waking up the code after sometime

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, apple-push-notifications, suspend

I am developing an application where we are continuously pinging the device from Server through remote notifications to check if the user is using the app (In Foreground / In Background / In Suspend) or not.

To do this I am sending remote notifications every 5 mins to the device. This remote notification wakes up my app. The app then calls a method on the sever saying "I am alive".

This is not a chatting application hence no socket. But I need to know if the user is in logged in state or not and hence continuous pings to check the status.

This works fine for me for 30-40 hours on iPAD but it only works 10-12 hours on iPhone.

After 12 hours on iPhone, I traced the logs I figured out that the device DID receive the notification, however it never woke up the code that could tell the server if the user was online.

Is there a limitation on the number of notifications that the device can receive from the server? Am i being too frequent? Also, would I be increasing the heap size or something which might be pushing the OS not to wake up my app?

Let me know if posting code would help. Thanks!

Comment: I am using Background Fetch as well as Remote Notifications as background mode.

Comment: I never heard about this kind of limitation but from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW7) 'Sending notifications too frequently negatively impacts the device’s battery life—devices must access the network to receive notifications.' So please don't do that, people will hate your app.

Comment: How do I get to know if the session on the device is active for the user? I need to know the status of the session on the device. Remote notification seems to be the only way. Any other solutions that you might think of?

Comment: Are you really have to know? You can send some info to server when user open app (`applicationWillEnterForeground` in appDelegate) or close (`applicationWillTerminate`) or go to background (`applicationDidEnterBackground`) and so on.